# Where do particles get energy to vibrate nonstop?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, atoms

The question is in the title.

This sentence has no conncection to the question. I wrote it because the site required the body of question have some text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vibrational energy of the atoms or molecules of an object is part of its thermal energy. A vibrating atom or molecule will emit electromagnetic radiation, typically in the infrared part of the spectrum for the temperature ranges that we encounter most of the time. Unless the energy carried away in this infrared radiation is replaced, then the amplitude of the atomic vibrations will decrease - in thermodynamic terms the atom or molecule will cool down.

However, objects do not exist in isolation - they interact with their surroundings. If an object is in thermal equilibrium with (i.e. at the same temperature as) its surroundings then it absorbs as much thermal radiation as it emits. It is this absorbed thermal radiation that replaces the lost thermal energy and keeps its atoms and molecules vibrating.